# How to import jinja2.ext.loopcontrols in DBT

Tags: dbt

I am using Jinja2 inside DBT. Jinja2 loop controls (break, continue) are not working. it is throwing below error:

Encountered unknown tag 'break'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.

I tried multiple ways but not able to import jinja2.ext.loopcontrols in DBT.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can't import `loopcontrols`</s> EDIT- I guess you CAN import it, but I wouldn't recommend altering the DBT code to do so.

You can just simply use `return()` if you want to break and don't have any logic after your loop.

If you don't want to use `return()`, you can do something like this

```
{% macro test() %}
  {% set break_tracker = namespace(is_finished = False) %}
  {% for i in range(5) if not break_tracker.is_finished %}
    {% if i == 3 %}
      {% set break_tracker.is_finished = True %}
    {% else %}
      // Do something
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, By adding 'jinja2.ext.loopcontrols' extention in your dbt setups Python38\Lib\dbt\clients\jinja.py file.
Add extension string 'jinja2.ext.loopcontrols' to def get_environment() method:

[image]